# proper grading fairness when certain questions dropped on exam

Tags: exams, grading

I had a 135 question final exam. The Professor decided 11 questions were problematic. For those 11 specific questions, he gave points to all students if they missed those questions. If a student got them correct no extra credit was given. Some students got more extra questions than others if they missed more of the 11. Is it unfair to not award the entire class same amount of wrong questions?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know what you're asking. Please clarify (1) Did you mean the professor added 11 more question to the make-up exam? (2) What do you mean by "_Some students got more extra questions than others if they missed more of the 11_"? Did those students take the exam the third time? Lastly, what do you mean by "_same amount of wrong questions_"? What are those _wrong_ questions?  Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @mkennedy The original post says "_Professor added back 11 specific questions to all students test if they missed them_". The OP did not say those 11 questions were problematic. Did the OP actually come back and explain this? Or you just guessed it so? Also, what does it mean by "_Some students got more extra questions than others if they missed more of the 11_"? That does not sound like those 11 questions were problematic or wrong in the first place. Did the OP actually explain this?

Comment: He credited points on 11 questions if a student missed them. That implies to me that the prof thought something was wrong with them.

Comment: @scaaahu For your later query, I think that statement goes along with the OP's statement that students who did get them right were not given any extra points. OP is seeing them as "free points" to the students that missed them.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common complaint.  Anytime a professor relaxes a requirement, the students who achieved it are unhappy (turn in time for a paper, whatever).

As far as those questions, it is not clear if professor decided they were wrong, ambiguous or just too hard.  In any case, what he did had the impact of removing them from any relative ranking (which is why the screams from those who got it right).

I wouldn't get outraged over it.  Sometimes there is no perfect answer. (Consider also the possible damage from leaving the questions in if they were flawed in some way.)  Just get over it, work hard, keep doing well.

Comment: The "get over it" advice is good for now. But after you receive your final marks, if your grade is within 1% from a grade cut off, it is worth contacting the professor saying something like "I'd just like to draw some attention to the way my grade was calculated. My answers on the 11 questions dropped from exam X showed a mastery of the material because __. It is clear I would have received grade Y if those questions were kept. While I know you dropped those questions would it be possible to discuss my grade in light of this unusual circumstance."